# Span deleted when change text in external div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a text and right of it to have a image (arrow up or down).
I used this code:

```
<div id="more-time1" class="small-text-size ">more time<span id="arr-icon" class="accordion_down"></span></div>
```

The external div holds the text and the internal span has the image (the image is data in the class).
When I change the text of the div:

```
var moreTime = document.getElementById("more-time1");
moreTime.innerHTML = "less time";
```

It delete span and I can't change the image in it unless I add every time a new span to it.

My question is:
Do I need to add span every time or I can have a better design which change text won't affect the span? Or maybe other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set .innerHTML of the div, you are writing its entire contents. This means you are overwriting the image span.

Put your text into a span so you can target the text separately from the image within the div.

```
<div id="more-time1" class="small-text-size ">
    <span class="more-time1-text">more time</span>
    <span id="arr-icon" class="accordion_down"></span>
</div>

var moreTime = document.getElementById("more-time1-text");
moreTime.innerHTML = "less time";
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly and simple

Answer (score 1):

You should surround your text inside an additional tag and then manipulate that.

HTML:

```
<div id="more-time1" class="small-text-size ">
   <span id="my-text">more time</span>
   <span id="arr-icon" class="accordion_down"></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
   var moreTime = document.getElementById("my-text");
   moreTime.innerHTML = "less time";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use code below to rich desired result:

```
var moreTime = document.getElementById("more-time1");
moreTime.childNodes[0].nodeValue = "Desired text"
```

**Explaining**: In code snippet above you accessing first child node of `more-time1` element (which is textNode) and modifying value of that node.

**Update:**
According to comment below to change text within your element you could start `for` loop over `childNodes`:

```
for (var latestTextNode, i=0; i < moreTime.childNodes.length; i++){
  if (moreTime.childNodes[i].nodeType == 3) {
    moreTime.childNodes[i].nodeValue = '';
    // keep link to latest text node to alter text later
    latestTextNode = moreTime.childNodes[i]; 
  }
};
latestTextNode && latestTextNode.nodeValue = 'Desired text';
```

Comment: This is not an ideal solution. If more elements are added to the div, this code may break.

Comment: greate comment, thanks, answer updated.